# Linux таймеры и сигналы реального времени

Tags: linux, c

Есть несколько таймеров, которые генерируют один и тот же сигнал SIGRTMIN дополнительно передавая в sival_int значение. Есть несколько обработчиков сигнала таймера. Правильно ли я понимаю, что сигнал гарантировано дойдет до всех обработчиков сигнала? А если сигнал сгенерируется одновременно несколькими таймерами?

Корректно ли в обработчике проверять sival_int ?

```
#define TIMER_EVENT_ID_1 1
#define TIMER_EVENT_ID_2 2

void timer_handler(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    if(info->si_value.sival_int==TIMER_EVENT_ID_1)
    {
        sem_post(&sem1); //будим трид 
    }   

    if(info->si_value.sival_int==TIMER_EVENT_ID_2)
    {
        sem_post(&sem2); //будим трид 
    }
}
```

В разных потоках я создаю, а потом сбрасываю и устанавливаю значения таймеров:

```
typedef struct 
{
    struct sigevent sigev;
    struct sigaction sa;
    struct itimerspec ival;
    timer_t tid;
} timer_data_t;

int init_timer(timer_data_t *timer_data, void *handler, UNS8 sigNum, UNS8 eventNum)
{
    timer_data->sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigemptyset(&timer_data->sa.sa_mask);
    sigaddset(&timer_data->sa.sa_mask, sigNum);
    timer_data->sa.sa_sigaction=handler;   

    if(sigaction(sigNum, &timer_data->sa, NULL)==-1)
    {
        perror("sigaction failed");
        return -1;
    }

    timer_data->sigev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    timer_data->sigev.sigev_signo = sigNum;
    timer_data->sigev.sigev_value.sival_int=eventNum;

    //создаем таймер
    if( timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &timer_data->sigev, &timer_data->tid)==-1)
    {
        printf("init_timer: не могу создать таймер! \n");
        perror("timer_create");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;       
}

int set_timer(timer_data_t *timer_data, UNS32 timeSec, UNS64 timeNsec)
{
    timer_data->ival.it_value.tv_sec=timeSec;
    timer_data->ival.it_value.tv_nsec =timeNsec;
    timer_data->ival.it_interval.tv_sec=0;
    timer_data->ival.it_interval.tv_nsec=0;

    if(timer_settime(timer_data->tid, 0, &timer_data->ival, NULL) == -1)
    {
        perror("timer_settime");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Т.е. вызывая init_timer, я просто изменяю обработчик для конкретного сигнала, т.к. он может быть только один?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю \*nix-ы, для каждого типа сигнала может быть активен только один обработчик (а как Вы собирались сделать несколько обработчиков для одного и того же сигнала?) . А вот разные таймеры могут генерировать разные сигналы, тогда для каждого таймера можно иметь свой обработчик. Все сигналы реального времени дойдут гарантировано. Обычные же сигналы одного типа не накапливаются.

Answer (score 3):

Не очень понимаю Ваш вопрос:

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что сигнал гарантировано дойдет до всех обработчиков сигнала?"

Что значит "до всех" ? Сигнал **всегда** доходит до обработчика сигнала, там обрабатывается и ИСЧЕЗАЕТ! Один сигнал не может дойти до двух обработчиков. В руководстве по сигналам написано, что если сигнал ожидают несколько обработчиков, то кто именно его получит - определяется реализацией.

Comment: Вы пишете: `В руководстве по сигналам написано, что если сигнал ожидают несколько обработчиков...`  Если Вы имеете в виду multithread программу, то укажите особо. А еще лучше конкретную ссылку на manpage приведите.

Comment: **В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса.** - не понял, какого РЕШЕНИЯ? Вопрос был:

**сигнал гарантировано дойдет до всех обработчиков сигнала?** и ответ на него может быть только да/нет. Я ответил - "нет". Что-то осталось непонятно?

Comment: **Если Вы имеете в виду multithread программу** - не обязательно. Сигналы передаются между процессами. Частным случаем которого является тред. Но я могу послать сигнал из одной ОДНОпотоковой программы в другую ОДНОпотококовую программу.

Comment: **лучше конкретную ссылку на manpage** - это невозможно, т.к. жизненный цикл сигнала описан не в каком-то конкретном ман-е, а в стандарте IEEE Std 1003.1b-1993.

На сайте intuit.ru есть очень хороший курс по POSIX-RT:

 http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/53/53/info

Но, на самом деле, даже этот курс изучать не обязательно. Мысль очень простая: после тго, как сигнал перехвачен и обработан, он удаляется ОС и больше уже никуда не идёт.